# Should a fragment have a different class to the activity it is used in?

Tags: java, android, list, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I intend to build a simple activity, with a list and a more detailed viewing panel. The list is populated with data from reading from a file. My question is whether the code for the two fragments should be in one activity, or in two separate activities and then called by another activity??
Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one activity.
To place both frags in screen use smth like this

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag1"
        android:name="your.pckg.frag1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>        
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frag2"
        android:name="your.pckg.frag2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Both frags are separated classes (in example case it is your.pckg.frag1 class and your.pckg.frag2 class)

Comment: If I want to add a TextView, Button or whatever to the fragment, do I just add it (in the XML) like I would for a LinearLayout??

Comment: So do I used on activity class, or two, with one initializing the other one?? For java code that is???

Comment: You've got xml files for every fragment. Sure, you can add any view you need. To be clear for your case (as I realized it) you have following files: 3 java files and 3 xml layouts. One java file for activity, 2 - for two fragments and same way for xml's.

Answer (score 1):

Why you want fragments? You can work around activities as the problem you explained will not need fragments to work with.

In case you want to work with fragments. Create it at runtime.

Create xml layouts of each fragment separately.
Create a fragment activity which will have these fragments as child
The class of fragments will extend class Fragment, while the parent will be extending FragmentActivity class.

Now, for the code, each fragment will have separate code of its own, no need to drop all in a single one i.e. parent one. Parent will be the owner to show or hide fragments or for callbacks of views that will be in child fragment.

But I would suggest, you to go through documentation present on android developer site before implementation.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize I could do it without fragments. This seems to be the normal example for the use of fragments in UI. Thanks for the help!!